# Connecting from Azure Databricks to Azure SQL using User Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to read data on an Azure SQL instance from an Azure Databricks workspace, avoiding using username/password personal credentials for automated, regular data fetch & analysis. I thought using a managed identity would do the job, however it looks to be less smooth than with Azure Functions or Web Services. Is this supported in Databricks?

I would need environment variables that do not exist in the Databricks instance, like IDENTITY_ENDPOINT and IDENTITY_HEADER, following the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Jokin, have you managed to connect? I'm facing the same use case but I can not find any good doc about it.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeFandango, I have not solved it, and I have been using SQL authentication instead with the credentials stored as secret in databricks. If you come up with a bettre solution, please share :)

Answer (score 0):

Those environment variables are there for added security and flexibility. When using a Managed Identity, you will have to request the access token to different providers, but if you want to simplify things, you can just hard code it like the sample below.

The IP address should never change, and if you're accessing other services besides SQL Database, just replace the "https://database.windows.net/" at the end. This is what the IDENTITY_ENDPOINT env variable is meant to be.

Once you have the access token, you're ready to access the SQL Server.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://database.windows.net/' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"}
$content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$content.access_token
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully connected from a Databricks workspace to Azure SQL database using a Managed Identity from a Python Notebook. (Note: no joy yet via the `CREATE CONNECTION` functionality which only seems to support SQL auth at present.)

When the workspace is created, a "managed" resource group is created along with a user assigned managed identity, visible under the resources of this managed resource group. This user assigned identity, `dbmanagedidentity` is assigned to the VMs which are provisioned when starting a cluster. You can give this identity access to your SQL database in the usual way<sup>1</sup>.

If your tenant has multiple `dbmanagedidentity` users, then you'll additionally need to use the `WITH OBJECT_ID` clause<sup>2</sup> to differentiate it (look up the Object ID from the managed identity resource).

**1. Create "contained" database user**

`CREATE USER [dbmanagedidentity] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH OBJECT_ID = '[object-id-guid-for-dbmanagedidentity]'`

**2. Give it the permissions it needs**

`ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [dbmanagedidentity];`

**3. Connect via python notebook**

```
jdbc_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://sql-example.database.windows.net;database=sqldb-example;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI;"
tbl = (spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", jdbc_url)
  .option("dbtable", "turtles")
  .load()
)
```

Helpful SO answer giving further insight into `FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76996864/1265167

---

<sup>1</sup> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-users-mapped-to-microsoft-entra-identities

<sup>2</sup> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#with-object_id--objectid