# Azure User Assigned ManagedIdentity authentication with Auzre DataBricks

Tags: python, azure, scala, databricks

"We've created a user-assigned managed identity and assigned the 'Contributor' role in our Databricks account under our subscription. Additionally, we assigned the 'Reader' role in SQL Server for the user-assigned managed identity in another subscription. However, when attempting to pull data from SQL Server to our ADB using ManagedIdentity authentication, we encountered an error stating 'credential is null'. Upon debugging the access token, we noticed that some other ManagedIdentity's credentials were appearing in both DefaultAzureCredential and ManagedIdentityCredential.

We've checked the URLs ("https://database.windows.net/.default,"https://management.azure.com/.default") for which credentials are authenticated, but they belong to a different ManagedIdentity which we didn't assign any role to, and it's not present in our resource. Can you please assist us in resolving this issue?"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To connect an SQL database with a user-assigned managed identity in Azure Data Bricks, you can follow the procedure below:

When the workspace is created, a "managed" resource group is created along with a user-assigned managed identity, visible under the resources of this managed resource group. Give access to the identity in sql database by following the procedure below:

Log in as an administrator into the SQL database, create a user for the Synapse workspace, and add the db_owner role using the code below:

```
CREATE USER [<identityName>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [<identityName>];
```

[image]

Use the code below to connect to the SQL database using MI authentication in a Data Bricks notebook:

```
jdbc_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://<serverName>.database.windows.net;database=<databaseName>;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI"
df = (spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", jdbc_url)
  .option("dbtable", "<tableName>")
  .load()
)
df.show()
```

It will connect successfully and display table data as shown below:

| contact soort | contact adres type | contact adres begindatum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 4-14b | sfa |
| BB | 4-14c | bds |
| CC | 23-17d | csc |

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855611/connecting-from-azure-databricks-to-azure-sql-using-user-managed-identity).